# two equivalent forms of BdG hamiltonians?

Tags: superconductivity

Consider two Bogoliubov - de Gennes Hamiltonians with equations for excitation energy,
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
H_{0} - E_{F} & \Delta \\
\Delta^{*} & E_{F} - \sigma_{y}H_{0}^{*} \sigma_{y}
\end{array} 
\right) \Psi_{0} = \mathcal{E}_{0} \Psi_{0} 
$$
and with $H_{0}$ replaced by $H = UH_{0}U^{\dagger}$, with some unitary opeator $U$,
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
UH_{0}U^{\dagger} - E_{F} & \Delta \\
\Delta^{*} & E_{F} - \sigma_{y}(UH_{0}U^{\dagger})^{*} \sigma_{y}
\end{array} 
\right)\Psi = \mathcal{E} \Psi 
$$
What the difference between $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{E}_{0}$, and also between $\Psi$ and $\Psi_{0}$. In my opinion it doesn't affect energies (they are the same), but the wavefunctions are changes in some way. How would You relate $\Psi$ to $\Psi_{0}$ (some transformation)?

Comment: Why do you need a transformation? If you know $H = UH_0U^\dagger$, then these two are the *exact same Hamiltonian*, are they not?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: You made a big mistake indeed ! What is called a transformation of a matrix is NOT the transformation of only a few of its elements, but a transformation of the WHOLE matrix, according to matrix multiplication. Please open a book of linear algebra. Here you  clearly forgot to transform the off-diagonal element, isn't it ?

Comment: No, its not what i meant. Sorry for this mess. Imagine You solve BdG equation using Hamiltonian $H$ and You find excitation enegies $\mathcal{E}$ and wavefunctions $\Psi$. Now, You realize that the Hamiltonian $H$ has some nicer form after unitary transformation $U$, so You get $H_{0} = U H U^{\dagger}$. And now, instead of using $H$ in Your calculations, You use $H_{0}$ and You ask yourself a question: Will the excitation energies and wavefunctions change? If so, what is the relations between the previously calculated stuff and this one?

Comment: How FraSchelle it said, you must transform the whole BdG matrix and not only the diagonal elements. Or you calculate the BdG equation with $UHU^{\dagger} and solve it.

Comment: Making the transformation of the whole BdG matrix is no the point in my question! I just showed You two DIFFERENT BdG Hamiltonians and I am asking if maybe there is some relation between energies and wavefunctions?